# Computing the median in a binary search tree

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree, median

Write the implementation of the function `ComputeMedian` that computes the median value in the tree in `O(n)` time. Assume that the tree is a BST but is not necessarily balanced.
Recall that the median of n numbers is defined as follows:
If n is odd, the median is x such that the number of values smaller than x is equal to the number of values greater than x. If n is even, then one plus the number of values smaller than x is equal to the number of values greater than x. For example, given the numbers
8, 7, 2, 5, 9, the median is 7, because there are two values smaller than 7 and two values larger than 7. If we add number 3 to the set, the median becomes 5.

Here is the class of binary search tree node:

```
template <class T>
class BSTNode
{
public:
BSTNode(T& val, BSTNode* left, BSTNode* right);
~BSTNode();
T GetVal();
BSTNode* GetLeft();
BSTNode* GetRight();

private:
T val;
BSTNode* left;
BSTNode* right;
BSTNode* parent; //ONLY INSERT IS READY TO UPDATE THIS MEMBER DATA
int depth, height;
friend class BST<T>;
};
```

Binary search tree class:

```
template <class T>
class BST
{
public:
BST();
~BST();

bool Search(T& val);
bool Search(T& val, BSTNode<T>* node);
void Insert(T& val);
bool DeleteNode(T& val);

void BFT(void);
void PreorderDFT(void);
void PreorderDFT(BSTNode<T>* node);
void PostorderDFT(BSTNode<T>* node);
void InorderDFT(BSTNode<T>* node);
void ComputeNodeDepths(void);
void ComputeNodeHeights(void);
bool IsEmpty(void);
void Visit(BSTNode<T>* node);
void Clear(void);

private:
BSTNode<T> *root;
int depth;
int count;
BSTNode<T> *med; // I've added this member data.

void DelSingle(BSTNode<T>*& ptr);
void DelDoubleByCopying(BSTNode<T>* node);
void ComputeDepth(BSTNode<T>* node, BSTNode<T>* parent);
void ComputeHeight(BSTNode<T>* node);
void Clear(BSTNode<T>* node);
```

};

I tried to write this function: I added two new member data `BSTNode<T>* med` and `int count` and this function compute the median only if the number of items is odd:

```
template <class T>
T BST<T>::ComputeMedian()
{
BSTNode<T> *median;
int numOfNodes = CountNodes();
if (numOfNodes % 2 != 0) {
    count = 0;
    ComputeOddMedian(root, numOfNodes/2);
    median = med;
    return median->val;

    }
else {
    count = 0;
    ComputeEvenMedian(root, numOfNodes/2);
    median = med;
    return median->val;

    }
return -1;
}

template <class T>
void BST<T>::ComputeOddMedian(BSTNode<T> *node, int x)
{
if (node->left) ComputeOddMedian(node->left, x);
count++;
if (count == x+1)
    med = node;
if (node->right) ComputeOddMedian(node->right, x);
}

template <class T>
void BST<T>::ComputeEvenMedian(BSTNode<T> *node, int x)
{
if (node->left) ComputeOddMedian(node->left, x);
count++;
if (count == x-1)
    med = node;
if (node->right) ComputeOddMedian(node->right, x);
}
```

It gives right results when the number of items is odd but it causes errors when the number of items is even (I think that is because there might be a NULL pointer). I feel that there is something wrong in my implementation especially with `return` in the recursion functions and with adding new member data.

*Edit:* 
For an odd number of items:

```
int main()
{
BST<int> tree;
int x=12;
tree.Insert(x);
x=6;
tree.Insert(x);
x=22;
tree.Insert(x);
x=3;
tree.Insert(x);
x=10;
tree.Insert(x);
cout << tree.ComputeMedian() << endl;
}
```

For the above code, the output is `10` which is true.

For an even number of items:

```
int main()
{
BST<int> tree;
int x=12;
tree.Insert(x);
x=6;
tree.Insert(x);
x=22;
tree.Insert(x);
x=3;
tree.Insert(x);
x=10;
tree.Insert(x);
x=17;
tree.Insert(x);
cout << tree.ComputeMedian() << endl;
}
```

For the above code, there is no output and this is a screenshot for the error:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Can you provide any test showing that it seems to work when number of items is odd and that it doesn't work when number of item is even ? Also, can you describe quickly the algorithm you are trying to apply ? Finally, why do the method ComputeXXXMedia return a BSTNode<T>* ?

Comment: I've added a main function for each case.
The algorithm that I'm following is to find the number of nodes in the tree then if the number is odd then ComputeOddMedian() is called and if even ComuteEvenMedian() is called. ComputeXXXMedian() traverse the tree **inorder** until it reaches the proper position then it makes the member med equal to the current node. I think that no matter what ComputeXXXMedian() returns in my code so you can ignore that.